# Web API Help is not generated, as per my exaptation

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I was written my API controller

```
[RoutePrefix("Office")]
public class OfficeController : ApiController
{                         
    [Route("{Admin}/{adminid}")]
    public string GetAdminById(int adminid) 
    {
        return string.Format("Enter value is {0}", adminid);
    }
    [Route("{User}/{userid}")]
    public string GetUserByName(int userid)
    {
        return string.Format("Enter value is {0}", userid);
    }
}
```

I am excepting Help generates like

GET Office/Admin/adminid

GET Office/User/userid

but generated web api help is below

GET api/Office?adminid={adminid}

GET api/Office?userid={userid} ------why ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra {} from action Route attributes.

`[Route("Admin/{adminid}")]`

and

`[Route("User/{userid}")]`

And read this [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Comment: i removed braces of {Admin} to [Route("~/Admin/adminid) and [Ropute(~/User/userid})]---but help is same not generated GET Office/Admin/adminid & Office/User/userid

Comment: your attributes should look like as i proposed in ansver, not like [Route("~/Admin/adminid)]